# Duplicated graphs in tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
a = tf.constant(5, name="input_a")
b = tf.constant(3, name="input_b")
c = tf.multiply(a,b, name="mul_c")
d = tf.add(a,b, name="add_d")
e = tf.add(c,d, name="add_e")
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("./tf_summary", sess.graph)
sess.run(e)
```

Nothing fancy here, just a very basic graph.

As you can see, there are two versions of the same graph in tensorboard, the second one having a suffix `_1` everywhere. I wonder why this happens?

Tensorflow version 1.2
Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Executing that code once yields a summary directory with a single graph. It might be that you have executed the script multiple times, so the duplicate seems to cover that.

Comment: I think tensorboard is caching some data in the browser. I need to remove the logdir, rerun the code,  restart the server  and then the graph shows up correctly.